# what does int (**p)[2] declare ? And what would be stored in array **p?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion

And what would be stored in array `**p`?

```
int main()
{
    int i, a[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
    int (**p)[2];
    p=a;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        printf("%d  ", *(*p+i));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `int (*p)[2]`?

Comment: As written, you have a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `int [2]`

Comment: Use https://www.cdecl.org/

Comment: `p = a;` only makes sense if p is `int (*p)[2];` otherwise the pointers are incompatible.

Comment: This code is wrong. `p=a` should give you at a warning or error, and the output is undefined (can be anything or crash).

Comment: @interjay `p=a;` is not an error as C has "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type" - although I'd expect a warning given the type mis-match.  The following code may have UB due to mis-alignment (rare) or AA trouble.  `printf("%d  ", *(*p+i));` is UB given mis-matched specifier/argument.

Answer (score 3):

> what does `int (**p)[2]` declare ?

[p as pointer to pointer to array 2 of int](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28**p%29%5B2%5D+)
(Very useful site [C gibberish ↔ English](https://cdecl.org))

> what would be stored in array `**p`?

In `**p` an array 2 of `int`.

`p` is a pointer.  `p` would also store a pointer.  That stored pointer in `p` points to an array 2 of `int`.

```
  int array2[2] = {5, 7};
  int (*pointer)[2] = &array2;
  int (**p)[2] = &pointer;
  printf("%d %d\n", (**p)[0], (**p)[1]);  // output "5 7\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo in this declaration.

```
int (**p)[2];
```

There must be

```
int (*p)[2];
```

That is it is a declaration of a pointer to array of the type `int[2]`

And in this assignment

```
p = a;
```

the array a is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element that has the type `int[2]`. That is in this assignment the right side hand operand has the type `int ( * )[2]` and the left side hand operand has the same type.

Otherwise you will get a compilation array because the pointers `int ( ** )[2]` and `int ( * )[2]` are not compatible,

In this for loop

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    printf("%d  ", *(*p+i));
```

there is in fact reinterpretation of the pointer to the type `int *`. As the pointer `p` has the type `int ( * )[2]` then dereferencing it you get lvalue of the type `int[2]` but used in the expression `*p+i` this array in turn is converted to pointer to its first element. That is inside the expression `*p+i` you have pointer to the element `a[0][0]`.

You could rewrite the expression

```
*(*p+i)
```

like

```
( *p )[i]
```

If to use a pointer of the type int( ** )[2] then the body of the function main could look like

```
int i, a[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
int (*q)[2] = a;
int ( **p )[2] = &q;

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    printf("%d  ", *( **p +i ) );
```

That is one more indirection of accessing elements of the array is added.

Answer (score 0):

The questioner's code does not compile:

```
int i, a[2][2]={{1,2},{3,4}};
int (**p)[2];
p=a;
```

error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'int [2][2]' to 'int (**)[2]'

If the intention was to define a pointer to the 2x2 array **a**, then **p** should be defined as a *pointer to array 2 of array 2 of int* and used thus:

```
int main()
{
    int a[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4} };
    int(*p)[2][2];

    p = &a;
    printf("{%d, %d} \n", (*p)[0][0], (*p)[0][1]);
    printf("{%d, %d} \n", (*p)[1][0], (*p)[1][1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:
{1, 2}
{3, 4}